# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'YearBuilt'

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, data-analysis

I'm trying to run this code but it's throwing a ValueError: counld not convert to float: 'YearBuilt' while the 'YearBuilt' column does not contain any Strings.

```
Score = pd.read_csv('Score_Data-No_Sale_Price.csv')
Score2 = Score[['PID','YearBuilt', 'YearRemodel', 'VeneerExterior','HeatingQC', 'FstFlrSqft',
       'AbvGrndLiving', 'FullBathHouse', 'RmAbvGrnd',
       'OverallQuality','LotArea', 'BldgTp']]
Score2.dtypes

_scaler = StandardScaler()
PDF_z2 = z_scaler.fit_transform(Score2.drop('PID', axis=1))
PDF_z2 = pd.DataFrame(PDF_z, columns=Score2.drop('PID', axis=1).columns)

imputer_by_median = SimpleImputer(strategy = 'median')
Scorecols = ['YearBuilt', 'YearRemodel', 'VeneerExterior','HeatingQC', 'FstFlrSqft',
       'AbvGrndLiving', 'FullBathHouse', 'RmAbvGrnd',
       'OverallQuality','LotArea', 'BldgTp']
dfImputeIntervalCols = PDF_z2[Scorecols].copy()
```

This is where the error occurs

```
Score3 = pd.DataFrame(imputer_by_median.fit_transform(Scorecols), 
                                      columns = Scorecols, index = dfImputeIntervalCols.index)

display(dfImputedIntervals.shape, dfImputedIntervals.dtypes, 
        dfImputedIntervals.isnull().sum().sum())
```

Comment: What is `Score2.dtypes` output?

Comment: @jezrael All int64, except 3 attributes. They are float64

Comment: @jezrael 'imputer_by_median.fit_transform(Scorecols)' 
Here lies the issue.